# Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{5 \times 5}$, then $A$ has...

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> a) an eigenvalue which is purely imaginary.
>
> b) at least one real eigenvalue.
>
> c) at least two eigenvalues which are not real.
>
> d) at least 2 distinct real eigenvalues.

[image]

Is this explanation correct?

Why is (c) not possible?

Is there any generalization for a square matrix of **odd** order?

Comment: For some ,suppose its true,then taking A=Identity matrix you get a 5x5 matrix with eigenvalues equals 1,for the rest remember that if $c\in\mathcal{C}$ is a root for $p(x)=0$ then so i the conjugate of $c$,does it helps?

Comment: Please write down your reasoning instead of uploading a picture. It will help us to answer your concerns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your explanation it's correct. For the (c) part
you can use one of these examples you have already used in (a) or (d). The key is that it's said that **at least** two eigenvalues are not real, which it's not an obligation.
Knowing that complex eigen values count two in the number of the dimension you can make a generalization ( I mean, for example in this exercise, if you got 2 complex eigen values, you have these numbers and their conjugates, so you have 4 eigen values, and the one left must be real)

Comment: :Can you give me an example of such a matrix?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=e404e38c6c4cd96cb134649299b8f58b you can use this one with:  $$\begin{bmatrix}
      6 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
       5 & 4 & 0 & 0 \\
       0 & 0 & 6 & -2 \\
       0 & 0 & 7 & 4 \\
   \end{bmatrix}$$ An fill last eigenvalue as you want